# NEWMAN & POSTMAN : Running collection with POSTMAN,but not with NEWMAN

Tags: postman, newman

Running collection with POSTMAN,but not with NEWMAN(With Environment.json).

My code under 'Tests' in 1st POSTMAN GET request:

```
pm.test("Retrieve cookie(TS01a20dbe)", function() {
let headerValue = pm.response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
var headerValue1 = headerValue.match(/TS01a20dbe=(.*); Path/)[1];
pm.environment.set("TS01a20dbe", headerValue1);
});
```

Note:
`pm.environment.set("TS01a20dbe", headerValue1);` - Updating 'TS01a20dbe' value in environment variable when I run above GET request from POSTMAN, but not updating when I run the same from NEWMAN. So 'TS01a20dbe' value is not passed on to next POST request. Please see below.

```
  {
"key": "Cookie",
"value": "TS01a20dbe={{TS01a20dbe}}; check=true; AMCVS_E9895AF6591C3FDF0A495C80%40AdobeOrg=1; 
}
```

Here is the command i'm using to run collection from NEWMAN

```
newman run <collectionName.json> -e <environmentFileName.json> --insecure
```

Comment: what error you are getting with above command ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - have you found any solution to your problem?